# Autopopulate search results using jquery in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a textbox called "Name" ,

when the user types a letter ,suppose "A" all the names beginning with the letter should be listed and user can select a name.

Is this kind of listing is possible using jquery in a MVC 3 application?

Comment: May be using Ajax functionality,controller which fetches the results to be called...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Jquery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) it can able to use in asp.net mvc3 application.

`var availableTags = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA"];
        $("#card_state").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });`

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.State, new { id = "card_state" })`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use jQuery + the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/